# Creating an ordinal variable from two numerical

Tags: r

**edit** Noticed a typo: minor 1 and hetero 1 equals **two**, not one as was written.

I have a dataset of genotypes, they are coded with two numerical variables (minorpos and heteropos) which can take either 1 or 0 (presence or absence of the marker). I want to make a third variable that translates this information into an ordinal variable so:

- minor 1 and hetero 1 equals two,
- or minor 0 and hetero 1 equals 1,
- or minor 1 and hetero 0 equals 1,
- or minor 0 and hetero 0 equals zero, and so on.

Here is a dataset to start:

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
BDNF_minorpos <- c(0, 1, 0)
BDNF_heteropos <- c(1,1,0)
EGFR_minorpos <- c(0,0,1)
EGFR_heteropos <- c(0,0,0)

mydata<-data.frame(BDNF_minorpos, BDNF_heteropos, EGFR_minorpos, EGFR_heteropos)
```

Will look like:

```
> data.frame(BDNF_minorpos, BDNF_heteropos, EGFR_minorpos, EGFR_heteropos)
  BDNF_minorpos BDNF_heteropos EGFR_minorpos EGFR_heteropos
1             0              1             0              0
2             1              1             0              0
3             0              0             1              0
```

I tried to create a function to do the job, but I am struggling with the ifelse syntax. It is the first function I am creating in R.

```
genotypesToOrdinals <- function(variables, data){
    for (i in variables)
        var_minor <- paste(i, "_minorpos")
        var_hetero <- paste(i, "_heteropos")
        x<- ifelse( (var_minor=0) & (var_hetero=0), 0,
            ifelse(var_minor=0) & (var_hetero=1), 1,
            ifelse(var_minor=1) & (var_hetero=0), 1,
            ifelse(var_minor=1) & (var_hetero=1), 2)
        data <- x
    return (data)
}
```

What I am tring to achieve is to pass the name of the variables (p.ex. BDNF and EGFR), then the function should locate the BDNF_minorpos and BDNF_heteropos, and create a new variable to hold 0, 1 or 2. It should also handle NAs, in case either is missing it should NA the entry.

I would like to call the function with:

```
genotypesToOrdinals(c("BDNF","EGFR"),mydata)
```

So far I am getting the error:

```
Error in ifelse((var_minor = 0) & (var_hetero = 0), 0, ifelse(var_minor = 0) &  : 
  unused arguments (1, ifelse(var_minor = 1) & (var_hetero = 0), 1, ifelse(var_minor = 1) & (var_hetero = 1), 2)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Perhaps the function is an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: Regarding your specific error, `?ifelse` takes 3 arguments. your 'inner' `ifelse`s are only given one : `ifelse(var_minor = 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update since question edit**

You can just use `rowSums` on each row.

```
genotypesToOrdinals <- function(variables, data){
    rowSums( data[, c(paste0(variables, c("_minorpos", "_heteropos")))] )
}


mydata$newBDNF <- genotypesToOrdinals("BDNF", mydata)
mydata$newEGFR <- genotypesToOrdinals("EGFR", mydata)


mydata
#    BDNF_minorpos BDNF_heteropos EGFR_minorpos EGFR_heteropos newBDNF newEGFR
# 1             0              1             0              0       1       0
# 2             1              1             0              0       2       0
# 3             0              0             1              0       0       1
```

Comment: `paste0` is vectorised by the way - `paste0("BDNF", c("_minor","_hetero"))` will work

Comment: edited the answer - can just use `rowSums` in this case

Answer (score 3):

Another use for `?interaction`:

```
stem <- c("BDNF","EGFR")
ordfun <- function(data,stem) c(0,1,1,2)[interaction(data[paste(stem,c("minorpos","heteropos"),sep="_")])]
mydata[paste(stem,"new",sep="_")] <- Map(ordfun, stem=stem, data=list(mydata))
mydata
#  BDNF_minorpos BDNF_heteropos EGFR_minorpos EGFR_heteropos BDNF_new EGFR_new
#1             0              1             0              0        1        0
#2             1              1             0              0        2        0
#3             0              0             1              0        0        1
```

To show why this works:

```
interaction(mydata[paste("BDNF",c("minorpos","heteropos"),sep="_")])
#[1] 0.1 1.1 0.0
#Levels: 0.0 1.0 0.1 1.1

c(0,1,1,2)[interaction(mydata[paste("BDNF",c("minorpos","heteropos"),sep="_")])]
#[1] 1 2 0
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach! the result from interactions should return unordered as per its description: `The result of ‘interaction’ is always unordered.` Should I be worried about it?

Comment: @lf_araujo - i wouldn't be worried about it. It will always work in the order of variables specified. If minor is followed by hetero in the function (as it is) then it should always be right.